# How do I add multiple data at once in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a field gender, age-group and patient_type. I want to store count for each patient type with age-group and gender. This is my form [formData](https://imgur.com/CmxJVIl). And this is array of data I get [arrayData](https://pastebin.com/EfqUHNrz). Also multiple age-group can be added.

For example, age-group=0-1, new_patient=>male=10,Female=60, old_patient=>male=50, female=20. How can I store this form data for multiple age-groups.

My Form code

```
<div class="newAgeGroup mt-5" id="newAgeGroup_0">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <label for="">Select Age Group</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-5 mb-3">
                        <select name="age_id[]" class="form-control" id="">
                            <option value="">Select Age Group</option>
                            @foreach($ages as $age)
                            <option value="{{$age->id}}">{{$age->start_age}}
                                -{{$age->end_age}}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <button type="button" onclick="addAgeGroup();"
                            class="btn btn-primary rounded-0 float-right addAgeGroup">Add Age Group
                        </button>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th></th>
                            @foreach($patient_types as $patient_type)
                            <th>
                                {{$patient_type->name}}
                                <input type="hidden" name="patient_type_id[]" value="{{ $patient_type->id }}">
                            </th>
                            @endforeach
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach($genders as $gender)
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                {{$gender->name}}
                                <input type="hidden" name="gender_id[]" value="{{ $gender->id }}">
                            </th>
                            @foreach($patient_types as $patient_type)
                            <?php 
                            $name = 
                            "number_".$patient_type->id."_".$gender->id ;

                            ?>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" name="{{ $name }}[]" class="form-control">
                            </td>
                            @endforeach
                        </tr>
                        @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                
        </div>
```

And this is what I have tried.

```html
foreach ($request->input('age_id') as $key => $value) {
            foreach ($request->input('patient_type_id') as $pt => $ptvalue) {
                foreach ($request->input('gender_id') as $gkey => $gvalue) {

                    foreach ($request->input('number_'.$ptvalue.'_'.$gvalue) as $nkey => $nvalue) {
                        $report = new Report();
                        $report->admin_id = $this->admin()->id;
                        $report->category_id = $request->center_type;
                        $report->center_id = $request->center_id;
                        $report->dateTime = $request->dateTime;
                        $report->nationality = $request->nationality;
                        $report->type = 'OPD';
                        $report->age_id = collect($request->get('age_id')[$key])->implode(',');
                        $report->patient_type_id = collect($request->get('patient_type_id')[$pt])->implode(',');
                        $report->gender_id = collect($request->get('gender_id')[$gkey])->implode(',');
                        $report->number = collect($request->get('number_'.$ptvalue.'_'.$gvalue)[$nkey])->implode(',');
                        $report->save();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is there any error message or what exactly does not work?

Comment: it works when i only insert data for one age group. but when i insert data for two age groups it stores 84 rows but actually it should be 42 rows.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand well, you want a single age group to have multiple records associated with it.

If that's the case I recommend you, to use relation in the database to achieve that.

For example these two tables:

| Age group | age group attributes |
| --- | --- |
| id | id |
| age | age_group_id |
|  | gender |
|  | patient type |

And when you save, the relationship will have you have counters and a better way to unite everything.

I hope this is useful to you.

Comment: If this is indeed what OP wants, [one-to-many relations](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) in Eloquent may be an interesting read. A patient belongs to an age group and an age group has many patients.

Comment: case in not only age group and counter but also gender and patient type. For eg, for particular age group how many male(gender) are new(patient types) patients. Also I already have relationship in database

Comment: I have same table as you recommended. But my code works when I only enter data for single age group. When I enter for two age groups it stores 84 rows but actually it should be 42 rows. since there are 3 genders and 7 paytient types.